# What part of this Solr-Sunspot setup am I missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, sunspot

I thought I had this down piece-of-cake .. but anytime I do a query on any keyword it doesn't load any tables from SQL. I get no errors.

**user.rb**

```
searchable do
  string  :first_name
  string  :last_name
  string  :name
  string  :email
  time    :created_at
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::ApplicationController

  def index
    s = Sunspot.search User do |query|
      query.keywords params[:q]
      query.any_of do |any_of|
        any_of.with(:first_name)
        any_of.with(:first_name)
        any_of.with(:email)
        any_of.with(:name)
      end
      query.paginate :page => (params[:page] && params[:page].to_i || 1), :per_page => 20
      query.order_by('created_at', 'desc')
    end

    s.execute!
    @users = s.results

    render :action => 'index'
  end
```

Then I ran:

```
$> script/console
$> User.reindex
```

When I make no search at all..it successfully displays all `User` results

I *believe* I am to make all those string tags into text tags but that returns this error:

```
Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError in Admin/usersController#index

No field configured for User with name 'first_name'
```

What am I missing to get this to respond to keywords?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*(A more complete explanation for your own self-followup.)*

Regarding your setup:

```
searchable do
  string  :first_name
  string  :last_name
  string  :name
  string  :email
  time    :created_at
end
```

A string in Solr is intended to be used for exact matches. It isn't pre-processed or tokenized the way a text column would be. These literal matches are used for filtering ("where category_name equals 'Sale'"), faceting, sorting, and so on.

You more likely want `text` fields. Text fields are tokenized with the [Standard Tokenizer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StandardTokenizerFactory), lowercased with the [LowerCase Filter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory), and have their dots and apostrophes removed with the [Standard Filter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StandardFilterFactory) among many other potential options.

When people think of the functionality of Solr's full-text search, they're thinking of how it processes `text` fields.

Furthermore, Sunspot's `keywords` search method by default searches against all of your text fields, which explains why you aren't getting results when you include `keywords` -- your documents have no text fields to search against.

As you note in your self-followup, you'll want to switch to `text` fields to get the results you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly the nicest answer, but I find that combining the strings and text tags together it works. So my User model looks like this :

```
searchable do
  text  :first_name
  text  :last_name
  text  :name
  text  :email
  time  :created_at
  string :first_name
  string :last_name
  string :name
  string :email
end
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, otherwise I get `Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError`