# Solr search not giving results for intermediate keywords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr

I also have a problem similar to

[What part of this Solr-Sunspot setup am I missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748288/what-part-of-this-solr-sunspot-setup-am-i-missing)

But, the problem is, I already applied the selected solution and have my searchable fields as `text`, still it won't work for intermediate strings. It only works for complete strings.

Eg:- `User.search (1, "adam")` will give me result for Adam, but this won't work:

```
User.search (1, "ad")
```

**My Code**

User Model

```
  searchable do
    text :firstname
    text :lastname
    text :email
    integer :some_id
  end
```

Search method

```
  def self.search(obj, search_text)
    solr_search do
      keywords search_text
      with(:some_id, obj.id)
    end
  end
```

Apart from this, I also tried following code:

```
  def self.search(obj, search_text)
    solr_search do
      keywords ''
      any_of do
        with(:email, search_text)
        with(:firstname, search_text)
        with(:lastname, search_text)
      end
      with(:some_id, obj.id)
    end
  end
```

But, I get following error in rails console:

```
> User.search(obj, "ad")
```

**Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError: No field configured for User with name 'email'**

Answer (score 0):

Fields configured as `text` will be `full-text` searchable. Other (`Scalar`) fields `integer, boolean, time and string` can be used to `scope queries`.

In your searchable block you have configured only text fields.

```
  searchable do
    text :firstname
    text :lastname
    text :email
    integer :some_id
  end
```

and your search method performing search on the scalar fields which are not defined in searchable block.

```
  any_of do
    with(:email, search_text)
    with(:firstname, search_text)
    with(:lastname, search_text)
  end
```

For make this work you have to define email, firstname and lastname fields as string in searchable block.

```
  searchable do
    text   :firstname
    text   :lastname
    text   :email
    string :firstname
    string :lastname
    string :email
    integer :some_id
  end
```

[Sunspot Search](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#sunspot)